# File system which supports trim command for shared SSD

Tags: linux, windows, ssd, filesystems, trim

I have a ~500GB SSD and I want to read/write on it from both of Windows and Linux.

As far as I know, there are three choices for file system of shared drives: FAT32, NTFS and exFAT.

- FAT32: Not an option because of absence of large file support
- NTFS: Supports large file but ntfs-3g does not support trim(discard)
- exFAT: Supports large file, too, and no idea about trim support in Linux(exfat-fuse)

I've heard that trim command is very important for better lifetime of SSD.
So, which filesystem should I use for shared SSD? If exfat-fuse does not support trim either, is there other option for me?

Answer (score 0):

ntfs-3g has trim support, upgrade to a newer version - http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.file-systems.ntfs-3g.devel/1101

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Just for clarification, are you recommending ntfs-3g as the solution, or just correcting the information about its trim support?